# ASP.NET core web application cannot connect to www through http proxy

Tags: asp.net-web-api, proxy, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a ASP.NET core web application (Kestrel) which serves as an authentication service (.NETCoreApp 1.1). Therefore it talks to an OpenID connect provider. It works all fine when the host machine is directly connected to the internet. However if the machine is behind the corporate web proxy of my company it cannot connect to the OpenID connect provider (or any other address in the www).

**How do I tell my ASP.NET core web application to use the corporate web proxy server?**

*Note: I already found some solutions which use web.config but that's no longer present in .NET core 1.1*

Comment: How's your app connecting to OpenID provider? I.e. what middleware/setup are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect (1.1.2).

`app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication( /* ...options... */ )`

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267113/how-to-configure-usecookieauthentication-behind-a-load-balancer ?

Comment: @ignas that actually seems to be the solution. Thank you!